# Python internal frame

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Is there any tkinter widget or window manager to realize internal frame (something like  [java internal frame](http://www.herongyang.com/Swing/JInternalFrame-Test.jpg))? Have done some search but couldn't see any discussion on python support of internal frame.

Comment: @qxz, did you notice that two incorrect tags were removed as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is nothing pre-built, but tkinter has all of the fundamental building blocks to implement it. The embedded windows are just frames, and you can place them in a containing frame with `place`. You can add your own border, and add mouse bindings to allow the user to move the windows around.

For what it's worth, usability experts long ago decided this type of UI isn't very user friendly.